# After Mavericks upgrade Chrome font is terrible

Tags: macos, google-chrome, font

I just upgrade to Mavericks and had some issues. Out of all the issues, one that I get frustrated the most is Chrome browser is not displaying font like it use to be. Here are two images taken from Safari and Chrome to compare.

Chrome:
[image: Chrome Browser]

Safari:
[image: Safari Browser]

As you can see, comparing both Safari and Chrome, fonts on Chrome are more bold.  I use Chrome mostly for my development and the font use in this design is Open Sans font-weight 300.

Is this normal or there is a fix to have Chrome render the fonts more finely as Safari does?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Mavericks issue.

Google Chrome has (currently) a bad support of Webfonts.

Comment: Yes, I did a few search and seems like that is the case. I just don't understand is when I was on Lion, chrome render the fonts just fine. Only after update is when I notice it. I use the same chrome version on both Lion and Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found that in Mavericks there was a change in system font.

The font used is Lucia Grande and it was optimized for retina in Mavericks.

If you want to change it back to ML there is a way in Terminal:

```
defaults write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 1
```

That would change it to Lucia Grande "Light" (10.8)

Comment: Give this a try and still font is not rendering correct. In the meantime I just use Safari for viewing and Chrome for developing.

Comment: @siQuang you will have to restart after changing the font